# Is there a way to grab the value that was passed to a method call?

Tags: java, methods

I was wondering if when I pass a value into a method call. Is there a way to grab the value directly from the method call?

```
int playerPosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500); //<-- Is there a way to grab this passed value?
        displayHighScorePosition("Perseus", playerPosition, 1500);//<-- Instead of hardcoding it in?
```

Here is the full code in question I was wondering about:

```
package com.company;

import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*boolean gameOver = true;
        int score = 800;
        int levelCompleted = 5;
        int bonus = 100;
        int highScore = calcScore(gameOver, score, levelCompleted, bonus);
        System.out.println("Your final score was " + highScore);
        score = 10000;
        levelCompleted = 8;
        bonus = 200;
        highScore = calcScore(gameOver, score, levelCompleted, bonus);
        System.out.println("Your final score was " + highScore);*/

        int playerPosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500); //<-- Is there a way to grab this passed value?
        displayHighScorePosition("Perseus", playerPosition, 1500);//<-- Instead of hardcoding it in?

        playerPosition = calculateHighScorePosition(900);
        displayHighScorePosition("Achilles", playerPosition, 900);

        playerPosition = calculateHighScorePosition(400);
        displayHighScorePosition("Hercules", playerPosition, 400);

        playerPosition = calculateHighScorePosition(50);
        displayHighScorePosition("Leonidas", playerPosition, 50);
    }

    /*public static int calcScore(boolean gameOver, int score, int levelCompleted, int bonus){
        if(gameOver){
            int finalScore = score + (levelCompleted * bonus);
            finalScore += 2000;
            return finalScore;
        } else {return -1;}
    }*/

    public static int calculateHighScorePosition(int highScore){

        if (highScore >= 1000){
            return 1;
        } else if (highScore >= 500){
            return 2;
        } else if (highScore >= 100){
            return 3;
        } return 4;
    }

    public static void displayHighScorePosition(String playerName,int playerPosition, int highScore){
        System.out.println(playerName + " managed to get into position "
                + playerPosition + " by scoring " + highScore + " points.");
    }
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/thinkexe/141dd7a6ac85c805b27bafc098b6d9c9)

Comment: What do you mean by _grab_? Can you just assign the value to a variable before the call and use the variable after?

Comment: I wanted to reduce the amount of variables I need to have. So I was wondering since calculateHighScorePosition  already has the value if I could somehow pass it along to displayHighScorePosition.

Comment: You could always write a function that does the pair of calls to `calculateHighScorePosition` and then `displayHighScorePosition`, and then call that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to [extract a method](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method), a bread and butter refactoring technique.

```
private static void calculateAndDisplayHighScorePosition(String name, int highScore) {
    int playerPosition = calculateHighScorePosition(highScore);
    displayHighScorePosition(name, playerPosition, highScore);
}
```

(You can probably come up with a better, shorter name.)

This gets rid of the repetitive logic in `main()`:

```
calculateAndDisplayHighScorePosition("Perseus", 1500);
calculateAndDisplayHighScorePosition("Achilles", 900);
calculateAndDisplayHighScorePosition("Hercules", 400);
calculateAndDisplayHighScorePosition("Leonidas", 50);
```

You could further reduce the repetition by saving the threshold scores in parallel arrays:

```
String[] names = {"Perseus", "Achilles", "Hercules", "Leonidas"};
int[] scores = {1500, 900, 400, 50};

for (int i = 0; i < names.length && i < scores.length; i++) {
    calculateAndDisplayHighScorePosition(names[i], scores[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do this by assigning it to a variable and passing that to both methods

```
int perseusPos = 1500;
int playerPosition = calculateHighScorePosition(perseusPos);
displayHighScorePosition("Perseus", playerPosition, perseusPos);
```